# Java pipes, why i get the write end dead exception

Tags: java, multithreading, pipe

i'm trying to create a program using pipes that communicate between 2 threads (you can say chat between 2 threads), my problem here is when you write there is no problem, but when you read from the pipe, it throws exception with end dead end. I did a send & receive method but my receive should know the length of string is sent by sender method, i did another receive method in same name without knowing the String length sent.

My code is composed of 3 classes as shown below :

```
package pipes1;
import java.io.*;

public class Pipe 
{
private PipedWriter writer;
private PipedReader reader;

public PipedWriter getWriter() 
{
    return writer;
}

public PipedReader getReader() 
{
    return reader;
}

public Pipe()
{
    writer = new PipedWriter();
    reader = new PipedReader();
}
}
```

========================================================

```
package pipes1;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Person 
{
private String name; //name of person
private String msg1;
private String msg2;
private Pipe pipe;

public String getMsg1() 
{
    return msg1;
}

public String getMsg2() 
{
    return msg2;
}

public Pipe getPipe() 
{
    return pipe;
}

public String getName() 
{
    return name;
}

public Person(String name,Pipe pipe,String s1,String s2)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.msg1 = s1;
    this.msg2 = s2;
    this.pipe = pipe;
}

public void connection(Person x) throws Throwable
{
    pipe.getReader().connect(x.pipe.getWriter());
}

public void closing() throws IOException
{
    this.pipe.getReader().close();
    this.pipe.getWriter().close();
}

public void send(String m) throws IOException
{
    this.pipe.getWriter().write(m);
    this.pipe.getWriter().flush();
}

public void recieve() throws IOException
{
    int data = this.pipe.getReader().read();

    while(data!=-1)
    {
            System.out.print((char)data);
            data = this.pipe.getReader().read();
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public void recieve(String m) throws IOException
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i<m.length())
    {
            System.out.print((char) this.pipe.getReader().read());
            i++;
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
}
```

==================================================================

```
package pipes1;

public class Main 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
{
    Pipe p1 = new Pipe();
    Pipe p2 = new Pipe();
    Person alice = new Person("Alice",p1,"recieved,thanks","hi bob");
    Person bob = new Person("Bob",p2,"hi alice","recieved, thanks");
    alice.connection(bob);
    bob.connection(alice);

    Thread terminal1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                bob.send(bob.getName()+":"+bob.getMsg1());
                bob.recieve(alice.getName()+":"+alice.getMsg1());
                bob.recieve(alice.getName()+":"+alice.getMsg2());
                bob.send(bob.getName()+":"+bob.getMsg2());
                bob.send("hi");
                bob.send("hi");
            } 
            catch (Throwable e) 
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    //terminal of a
    Thread terminal2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                alice.recieve(bob.getName()+":"+bob.getMsg1());
                alice.send(alice.getName()+":"+alice.getMsg1());
                alice.send(alice.getName()+":"+alice.getMsg2());
                alice.recieve(bob.getName()+":"+bob.getMsg2());
                alice.recieve();
                alice.recieve();
            } 
            catch (Throwable e) 
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    terminal1.start();
    terminal2.start();
}
}
```

=================================================================

and the result is this :

Bob:hi alice

Alice:recieved,thanks

Alice:hi bob

Bob:recieved, thanks

hihiWrite end dead

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace();` instead of `e.getMessage();` to show the full stacktrace for an exception.

Answer (score 1):

A thread that wrote to a pipe ended without closing the pipe, leaving the pipe [broken](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html#BROKEN). A subsequent attempt to read from the `PipedReader` detected this and threw an `IOException`.

From the javadoc for the method [PipedReader.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedReader.html#read()):

> **public int read()**
>
> throws IOException
>
> ...
>
> **Throws:**
>
> IOException - if the pipe is broken, unconnected, closed, or an I/O error occurs.

From the javadoc for [PipedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html#BROKEN):

> A pipe is said to be broken if a thread that was providing data bytes to the connected piped output stream is no longer alive.

I think you can avoid the error by adding `bob.closing()` in the first thread. (I haven't tested that.) Each writer thread should really close the pipe to which it's writing.

Comment: i tried it, and the exception died, now i have a new issue here. is when i send a message from thread 1 to thread 2 then from thread2 to thread1 it doesnt work, its look like a deadlock happening.

Comment: Well, I was going to suggest calling `flush()` on the writer, but you're already doing that. Good! Next step would be to follow through with a debugger. If that doesn't help, you can start a new stackoverflow question for the new issue. If it is a deadlock, be sure to indicate where the threads are stuck.

Comment: okay, i will try to do a debugging, until I'm stuck and i will do a new question here, thanks my brother in java, you saved me in half of my problem.